# Query for system (not JVM) uptime in Java

Tags: java, operating-system, monitoring, jmx

Is there a OS-neutral method of querying for system (not JVM - I am aware of RuntimeMXBean.getUptime()) uptime in JavaSE 6 ?

Thanks

Comment: I would be surprised if there is an OS-neutral way of querying for system uptime, but it would be nice to have.

Comment: My hope was that there is some nice Java abstraction above all the differences...

Comment: It's a shame Java don't has stuff like this. They always go for the lowest common denominator and this limits the programmer. They done this in the GUI, for stuff like tray icons, and this might be one reason why Java is so unsuccessful on the desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.

- There are *system specific* ways of querying uptime (e.g. uptime on *nix)
- There are ways to [detect the operating system](http://objectmix.com/java/71837-can-java-detect-host-os.html).
- There is a small finite number of likely operating systems.
- And you're in a general purpose programming environment, so...

Answer (score -1):

so it shoudln't be a big deal that they implement it, since they are writting specific JRE for each platform, which is aware of uptime() version for each OS, and they could easily wrap it into some java call, like getSystemUptime()