# How to get UNIX uptime in Java?

Tags: java, unix

What is the best way to get the UNIX uptime in Java? Is there a standard Java library/function I could use or should I use Runtime's exec or ProcessBuilder to execute 'uptime'? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query for system (not JVM) uptime in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674106/query-for-system-not-jvm-uptime-in-java)

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz I saw that question earlier but it seems to ask for a platform agnostic solution. I'm looking for something that can work specifically on Nix machines

Comment: Sorry, and I actually found such a *NIX solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can read `/proc/uptime`:

```
new Scanner(new FileInputStream("/proc/uptime")).next();
//"1128046.07" on my machine and still counting
```

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uptime):

> Shows how long the system has been on since it was last restarted:

```
$ cat /proc/uptime
  350735.47 234388.90
```

> The first number is the **total number of seconds the system has been up**. The second number is how much of that time the machine has spent idle, in seconds.

Comment: That's good for Linux, but not all UNIX systems. You can see from your Wikipedia link that it won't work on BSD, for example.

Comment: according to my test on RHEL second number is idle time of all processors, so it can be bigger than first one

`$ cat /proc/uptime
2418163.50 4809606.42`

Answer (score 3):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec('uptime');
```

Did you try this? The only command that does something equivalent to `system('uptime');` in java is `runTime.exec()`. Thats all I could think of ..

Answer (score 3):

This is likely to be entirely system dependant but you can use `System.nanotime();`

```
System.out.println("/proc/uptime " + new Scanner(new FileInputStream("/proc/uptime")).next());
System.out.println("System.nanoTime " + System.nanoTime() / 1e9);
```

prints

```
/proc/uptime 265671.85
System.nanoTime 265671.854834206
```

Warning: This is unlikely to work on all platforms.