# how to get the startup time of the play framework?

Tags: playframework

I need to retrieve the startup time of the play framework. I added the code to get the startup time inside the onStart method in the Global. However, it only collects the startup time when it receives the first request.

What i need is
1.Get the time when the play framework(web server) starts.
2.Is there any API for me to get the start up time of the physical server?

Comment: BTW it was better if you gave us more info, like used Play version, used OS, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app starts after first request, because you are starting it in dev mode instead production, don't you?

In this case Play waits for first request, always. If you'll start app with `play start` it will invoke `beforeStart` and `onStart` methods as soon as possible without waiting for request.

If you want also to measure time required for downloading dependencies and compilation I'd use ie. some shell script which first will create some file like `start.txt` and then will run your app with `play start`. Next in your `onStart` you can compare time between current time and time of file's creation.

Getting `uptime` of the physical server is dependent on the OS, so you need to search additionally for your current machine. i.e. for Linuxes it could be [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8209162/1066240)

Answer (score 0):

you can use logs of playframework.
to get the information like when it connects with database
**2014-03-01 11:02:02**`INFO ~ database [default] connected at jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.6:3306/databasename`
   and many more like exceptions and errors, which are related to your play framework.
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.1.1/logs

MY LOG FILE

```
2014-03-01 11:12:02  INFO ~ Stopping server...
2014-03-01 11:17:39  WARN ~ releaseHelperThreads has been deprecated -- it tends to slow down your application more.
2014-03-01 11:17:39  WARN ~ releaseHelperThreads has been deprecated -- it tends to slow down your application more.
2014-03-01 11:17:39  WARN ~ releaseHelperThreads has been deprecated -- it tends to slow down your application more.
2014-03-01 11:17:39  WARN ~ releaseHelperThreads has been deprecated -- it tends to slow down your application more.
2014-03-01 11:17:40  INFO ~ database [default] connected at jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.6:3306/databasename
2014-03-01 11:17:40  INFO ~ Application started (Prod)
2014-03-01 11:17:40  INFO ~ Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
2014-03-01 11:18:04  INFO ~ Shutting down connection pool...
2014-03-01 11:18:04  INFO ~ Connection pool has been shutdown.
2014-03-01 11:18:04  INFO ~ Shutting down connection pool...
2014-03-01 11:18:04  INFO ~ Connection pool has been shutdown.
2014-03-01 11:18:04  INFO ~ Shutting down connection pool...
2014-03-01 11:18:04  INFO ~ Connection pool has been shutdown.
2014-03-01 11:18:04  INFO ~ Shutting down connection pool...
2014-03-01 11:18:04  INFO ~ Connection pool has been shutdown.
2014-03-01 11:18:04 ERROR ~ Error while stopping logger
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind it only kinda working on your development machine, but working when deployed. You can use the solution I am using:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Period;
import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatter;
import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatterBuilder;
import play.Logger;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import java.io.File;

public class ControllerWithUptime extends Controller {
    private static DateTime launched = null;

    public static String getUpTime() {
        final Period period = new Period(getLaunched(), DateTime.now());
        final PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
                .appendYears().appendSuffix(" years, ")
                .appendMonths().appendSuffix(" months, ")
                .appendWeeks().appendSuffix(" weeks, ")
                .appendDays().appendSuffix(" days, ")
                .appendHours().appendSuffix(" hours, ")
                .appendMinutes().appendSuffix(" minutes, ")
                .appendSeconds().appendSuffix(" seconds")
                .printZeroNever()
                .toFormatter();

        return formatter.print(period);
    }

    private static DateTime getLaunched() {
        if (launched == null) {
            final String path = play.Play.application().path().getAbsolutePath() + "/RUNNING_PID";
            final File pidFile = new File(path);
            if (pidFile.exists()) {
                launched = new DateTime(pidFile.lastModified());
            } else {
                Logger.warn("Using fallback to determine uptime - which is ok while developing...");
                launched = new DateTime();
            }
        }
        return launched;
    }
}
```

Basically I am using the timestamp of the PID file for the running application with a fallback of first usage. The method `getLaunched()` might be all you need, but `getUpTime()` returns nicely formatted string (although it has a dependency on Joda Time).