# Get system uptime in Java

Tags: java, system

How can I determine how long (in milliseconds) a computer has been powered on?

Comment: that depends on the OS, but you'll probably want to shell out a command

Comment: what OS? .. no way without an external third party library or JNI.

Comment: or look at http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-get-time-in-milliseconds-in-java/

Comment: @aniket it's also platform dependent whether you *need* an external library. On linux you just read `/proc/uptime` file.

Comment: It would depend on the OS. For unix, you can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209096/how-to-get-unix-uptime-in-java

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/674176/1979005

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Windows, you can execute the `net stats srv` command, and in Unix, you can execute the `uptime` command.  Each output must be parsed to acquire the uptime.  This method automatically executes the necessary command by detecting the user's operating system.

Note that neither operation returns uptime in millisecond precision.

```
public static long getSystemUptime() throws Exception {
    long uptime = -1;
    String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
    if (os.contains("win")) {
        Process uptimeProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("net stats srv");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uptimeProc.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.startsWith("Statistics since")) {
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("'Statistics since' MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
                Date boottime = format.parse(line);
                uptime = System.currentTimeMillis() - boottime.getTime();
                break;
            }
        }
    } else if (os.contains("mac") || os.contains("nix") || os.contains("nux") || os.contains("aix")) {
        Process uptimeProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("uptime");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uptimeProc.getInputStream()));
        String line = in.readLine();
        if (line != null) {
            Pattern parse = Pattern.compile("((\\d+) days,)? (\\d+):(\\d+)");
            Matcher matcher = parse.matcher(line);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                String _days = matcher.group(2);
                String _hours = matcher.group(3);
                String _minutes = matcher.group(4);
                int days = _days != null ? Integer.parseInt(_days) : 0;
                int hours = _hours != null ? Integer.parseInt(_hours) : 0;
                int minutes = _minutes != null ? Integer.parseInt(_minutes) : 0;
                uptime = (minutes * 60000) + (hours * 60000 * 60) + (days * 6000 * 60 * 24);
            }
        }
    }
    return uptime;
}
```

Comment: @KerrM My bad on not noticing your comments sooner somehow! On a Mac, what is the output format for the first hour? I actually wrote the OSX/Linux portion of this method based entirely off of documentation, as I don't have easy access to either type of OS.

Comment: @JavDev Currently in the midst of finals but writing myself a note to come back to this in a few days since I've got easy access to a linux system now. I'll ping you again once that happens!

Comment: Voted this answer down as it only works on Windows if your OS language and settings matches what is in the proposed SimpleDateFormat. If the date format is changed in the OS settings the date/time pattern will not match. Same thing, if your OS language is not english 'Statistics since' will be printed in OS language in the net command output and won't match. So the answer may work on your computer but not on client sites in foreign countries.

Comment: @jumar Great point. Does iTech's answer work with other languages?

Comment: On Windows 10 Enterprise, I had to change `net stats srv` to `net stats workstation`.

Answer (score 9):

Use the [OSHI library](https://github.com/oshi/oshi/blob/master/oshi-core/src/main/java/oshi/hardware/CentralProcessor.java) which works on Windows, Linux and Mac OS.

```
new SystemInfo().getOperatingSystem().getSystemUptime()
```

Comment: "Windows, Linux and Mac OS" and FreeBSD and Solaris. ;)

Comment: @DanielWiddis I didn't know, thanks. Makes OSHI even more convincing!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [OSHI](https://github.com/oshi/oshi) library. here is the sample code

```
System.out.println("Uptime: "+FormatUtil.formatElapsedSecs(new oshi.SystemInfo().getOperatingSystem().getSystemUptime()));
```

For getting it work need to add the following dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.oshi</groupId>
    <artifactId>oshi-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't really think of a non OS dependant way to do this.
An option would be to use `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getUptime();`
Which returns your JVM uptime so not exactly what you're looking for but already a step in the right direction.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish with the data?

Comment: in which datatype the result is returned? i am looking for system logged in time to use in my application to give an alert to users that system has not been shutdown for specific hours. please update code if any. thanks

Comment: @JavDev returns the amount of milliseconds of uptime as a long

Answer (score 2):

For windows you can get `uptime` to milliseconds accuracy by querying `windows WMI`

To run the below code, you will need to download [Jawin](http://heanet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/jawinproject/jawinproject/Jawin-2.0-alpha1/jawin-2.0-alpha1.zip) library and add `jawin.dll` to your eclipse project root

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws COMException {
    String computerName = "";
    String userName = "";
    String password = "";
    String namespace = "root/cimv2";

    String queryProcessor = "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem";

    DispatchPtr dispatcher = null;

    try {

        ISWbemLocator locator = new ISWbemLocator(
                "WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
        ISWbemServices wbemServices = locator.ConnectServer(computerName,
                namespace, userName, password, "", "", 0, dispatcher);
        ISWbemObjectSet wbemObjectSet = wbemServices.ExecQuery(
                queryProcessor, "WQL", 0, null);
        DispatchPtr[] results = new DispatchPtr[wbemObjectSet.getCount()];
        IUnknown unknown = wbemObjectSet.get_NewEnum();
        IEnumVariant enumVariant = (IEnumVariant) unknown
                .queryInterface(IEnumVariant.class);

        enumVariant.Next(wbemObjectSet.getCount(), results);

        for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            ISWbemObject wbemObject = (ISWbemObject) results[i]
                    .queryInterface(ISWbemObject.class);

            System.out.println("Uptime: "
                    + wbemObject.get("LastBootUpTime"));
        }
    } catch (COMException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted solution without library and using WMIC was best fit for me.

```
private DateTime getSystemBootTime() throws IOException {
    String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
    if (os.contains("win")) {
        Process uptimeProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("WMIC os get lastbootuptime");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uptimeProc.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.startsWith("ERROR")) {
                logger.error("CheckMachineUptime failed. WMIC operation failed. MACHINE OS: {} CMD output: {}", os, line);
                break;
            }
            if (line.startsWith("2")) {
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
                try {
                    return new DateTime(format.parse(line));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        logger.error("Task failed! Could not identify time format. CMD OUTPUT: {}", in.readLine());
    } else logger.error("Task failed! Could not identify machine OS. MACHINE OS: {}", os);
    throw new RuntimeException("Getting uptime failed");
}
```

Thanks to FThompson and commenters in this thread.