# Determine the time the computer was turned ON using Java

Tags: java, startup

I have a Java JAR program that is run on Windows startup. It needs to register the time the computer was turned on, so naturally it simply gets the time when the `main` method is called. Works fine.

But, some of the computers we installed the program in are very (very) slow. It is unsurprising that the startup of the program may occur after several minutes upon turning on the computer.

An inaccuracy of 10-15 seconds is acceptable (our newest computers). But two or three minutes in the oldest ones not quite so.

Is there a reasonable way to determine the time the computer was turned ON? Using Java?

I do realize that for this kind of job, Java was a terrible choice. It is well known that Java startup is not particularly fast at all. I'll ask this anyway since the program is already done with Java - but if there is no solution I'll work on a C++ version.

Windows.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14800849/4028085

Comment: You can use that to find the uptime then subtract uptime from current time to get start time

Answer (score 2):

What about write short *.bat file, with only one functionality - after start it writes actual time to a file.

When your Java program is loaded, it just first try to read file and find out the time of computer start.

---

Maybe even better idea - start your program through .bat file. First get actual time and save it to variable, then start program with value of this variable as parameter. When the program is on, it will first recieve the time of start in main method.

Comment: That's a pretty nice idea! I will consider it.

Comment: actually that won't give you the exact start time as well, only the time the .bat gets around to being executed. Using for example "systeminfo" command would give you the right time, plus you would not have to deal with filesystem permissions etc.

Comment: This is not the time when the system has booted. If there are many batch file to execute at start time it is strongly influenced from other batch. In addition there is not guarantee that this time is used by other internal thread s of the os to perform other activities.

Answer (score 2):

There are [several options](https://superuser.com/questions/523726/how-can-i-find-out-when-windows-was-last-restarted) to find this out on Windows:

```
systeminfo | find /i "Boot Time"
```

(As noted by @Robert this only works on English Windows installations)

or

```
wmic os get lastbootuptime
```

or

```
net statistics workstation
```

Just use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command");` to call the command.

Comment: `systeminfo | find /i "Boot Time"`only works on Windows system with English as display language. I would recommend to use `wmic os get lastbootuptime` as it uses a language and region independent format as output format.

Answer (score 0):

You can try launching from within Java (using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)`) a command that will give you the exact machine start time (`systeminfo`) or uptime (there is a Microsoft utility uptime.exe).

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: beats me - I think it's the most accurate answer to the problem. You can always upvote :)

Answer (score -2):

This is not a java related question.

It is a question operating system related.

If your operating system has a function that gives you this information you can call that function

The code to call an os function from java is

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command");
```

In linux the commandline command to get the information of the last boot is the following:

```
last reboot | head -1
```

As I said it depends from operating system to operating system.

For a windows environment you can use the following code:

```
systeminfo | findstr /C:"System Boot Time"
```

Comment: It's a Java question because I want to do it with Java. The way to call such function from the OS in Java is not necessarily the same way to call it in another language. And if you're not going to answer this question, make this a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I edited the answer. I said that is not a java related question because java hasn't the information about when the system has been booted. It is an information of the operating system. If your problem is how to call an operative system function and retrieve the results the question is bad exposed

Comment: Calling such OS function is **one** solution, but it may or may not be the ***only*** (or best) solution. Asking how to call the OS function instead of laying down my core problem is equivalent to assuming that this is the best answer (which may or may not be) and would discard any other possible solution (like libik's answer for example) that could perhaps be more or less useful/convenient.

Comment: @Voldermort I already commented the solution of libik.

Comment: Yes and as I said, it is better to lay down the core problem to see all options I have. As the asker, I can't just assume what is the best solution without having seen the options.

Comment: If the OS executes your java code after minutes it will executes also a batch file after minutes. So if you are asking for a different approach to solve your problem I can't imagine how delegate it to a bat instead to a jar can solve the problem.

Comment: **Never did I say that his solution is better than calling an OS function.** What I said is that it is better to see the options **before** picking the answer. And to do so, I must lay down the core problem instead of running into assumptions. Hence I can't just ask "how do I call an OS function" as it would invalidate alternative answers that may (**or may not**) be better. This isn't about libik's answer in particular - I mentioned it as an example to prove that alternative methods exist and must be accounted for, **regardless of being better or worse**.